# std::map Access Speed Is Too Slow?

Tags: c++, dictionary, entity, std

I have recently been implementing an Entity-component system for my game engine. Every entity keeps a map of components like that :

Component.h

```
enum COMPONENT_INFO {
    COMPONENT_POSITION = 0, 
    COMPONENT_PHYSICS,
    COMPONENT_RENDERABLE
 };
```

Entity.h

```
class Entity {
public:
    std::bitset<NUM_COMPONENTS> componentBits;
    std::map<COMPONENT_INFO, Component*> components;
    ..
    ..

    Component *getComponent(COMPONENT_INFO inf) {
        return components[inf];
    }
 };
```

And my System class updates every entity per frame like that :

```
void update(Entity *e, float delta) { 
        PositionComponent *cmp=(PositionComponent*)e->getComponent(COMPONENT_INFO::COMPONENT_PHYSICS);
        //x += 1.0f;
        cmp->x += 1.0f;
    }
```

Everything works as intended, but I have a huge performance problem in accessing the map. When I create 10000 entities and iterate through them (the system iterates through actually), I get 80 FPS with a blue blank system(no visual effects, just plain screen). But when I comment out the access parts and only use `x += 1.0f;`, FPS increadibly increases to 1000. Like that :

```
void update(Entity *e, float delta) { 
        x += 1.0f; //btw the system has a local x value.
    }
```

So the problem is simply at accessing the components through the map. What else can I use on a system like that ? Or maybe I am doing something wrong in accessing the map ?

Important Edit : This is just a test drive, I mean there might be lots of components per entity, not just 3. I wrote these for just testing purposes.

Comment: Given that you only have three keys, you could use a plain array, or an `std::array<Component*, 3>`. But are you sure the problem really is in the access to map elements?

Comment: Yes the problem is at accessing to map elements (even though i remove cmp->x line, fps is still 80). There won't be 3 keys by the way. For example If i have 64 different components, all of the entities will have to hold them seperately if I use fixed arrays.

Comment: Can you cache the result of the map in your class to prevent repeated lookup?

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, your method getComponent is using operator [] which not only retrieves instance with given key, but if not present, inserts an element.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/

In given implementation you limit yourself to one component of each type in an entity which might not be the best option. For example you might want to have a few renderable component for one entity doing various things like particles, mesh rendering etc.

Map does not guarantee that object are laid in memory sequentially which might cause a cache miss when processed one by one. It would be more efficient to use std::vector for example, and keep the COMPONENT_INFO in the component object itself.

Another solution would be to add methods to your system class that would create particular types of components and while doing so, doing some bookeping about each component instance. System could then keep vectors of each component type and do batch processing on those.

Hope this will help a bit.

Edit:

The idea is that when you add/create new Collision component the component itself registers in the system providing type and pointer to itself. The same for renderables etc. You can have map of vectors for each component type in your system. When you need to resolve collsion you just retrieve all your collidables (reference to a vector). You make one lookup which is log(n) and then iterate over all collidables (the pointers due to being in vector are layed out sequentially in memory making it more cache friendly).

Also do you test performance in release build?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, components are not fixed, i might add lots of them. This is just a test. Since the systems are checking the entities, even though i use vectors I need to know where exactly the element is at, if i don't map them i will again spend O(n) time to find which component i am talking to

Comment: Hmm, release version is 4x faster, let me try on -O2

Answer (score 2):

Since the number of components per entity appears to be fixed, I would ditch the map and use member variables in Entity to hold each component, along with a getter. This will also avoid the cast in your update function:

```
class Entity {
private:
    PositionComponent* m_positionComponent;
    PhysicsComponent* m_physicsComponent;
    RenderableComponent* m_renderableComponent;
public:
    // initialize the components in the constructor
    PositionComponent* getPositionComponent() {
        return m_positionComponent;
    }

    // more getters for the other components
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to have more component types and want to keep the design flexible, you might want to store them in a vector, using the enum values to index it. This will avoid the map lookup altogether and will give you better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are not only 3 components. NUM_COMPONENTS is for keeping the bitset. About the vectors, If i use that, i will have to reserve NUM_COMPONENTS element per entity which will be expensive (in order to randomly access it, i must reserve some space i think ?)

Comment: By the way I tried the vector and enum-indexing solution, yes it speeds up (like to 500 fps) but as I said, it will cost NUM_COMPONENTS * 4 bytes for even the smallest things like particles.

Comment: I understand your predicament, but often you have to trade space for speed. However, in this case I would probably go back to the drawing board; maybe there is a design that also solves your problems while being less general, but more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

As your highest number of `COMPONENT_INFO` is fixed you could use an `array<Component*>` (or `vector<>` and use e.g. `myArray[COMPONENT_INFO::COMPONENT_PHYSICS]` for addressing. You might have to check for nullptr, though.

Comment: It will keep 4 * NUM_COMPONENT unnecessary memory for each entity then.

Comment: @deniz, that may be far less than the overhead added by using a map - each node has a pointer to parent, left and right, plus for an RB tree, it also has a colour - that's 4 x the cost of a single pointer in memory usage.